# css: floating div affects content of non-floating div

Tags: css, css-float

I've just finsished the google css walkthrough: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/

After experimenting with the example files (file: css-walkthrough.html), I found some strange behavior, I couldnt explain.

I have three divs in a container div:

```
<div id="wd-c">

  <div id="wd-1"><span>1</span></div>

  <div id="wd-2"><span>2</span></div>

  <div id="wd-3"><span>3</span></div>

</div>
```

We have the follwing css, which renders as expected: all 3 divs are taken 'out of the flow', and displayed in one line. The content spans are inside the divs.

```css
#wd-c div {
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: .7;
}

#wd-c div { width: 150px; }
#wd-c #wd-1 { width: 50px; } /*for clarity*/      

#wd-1 { float: left }
#wd-2 { float: left }
#wd-3 { float: left }
```

However, when I uncomment:

```
/*#wd-3 { float: left }*/
```

div #wd-1 and #wd-2 are still rendered 'out of the flow', #wd-3 is rendered as block element, overlapping the other 2.

The strange thing is that the content span with the character 3, appears below all divs and is not inside #wd-3 anymore.

It appears as if the content of #wd-3 is affected by the floating divs, which is obviously wrong. For instance, when I change the width of #wd-3 to

```css
#wd-c #wd-3 { width: 220px; }
```

the character renders inside the div, just beside the overlapping floating div #wd-2 .. do you have any explanation?

Comment: Perhaps yet another clear:both issue. If you need to float, then clear the container or add a clearing div. Ideally find a different way than floating at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite logical. `float`doesn't take the according element out of the document-flow like `position:absolute` does.

Normally, an element "respects" nearby floating elements and tries to display it's content accordingly. Now by removing `float` on your third div, it gets drawn below the floated divs. However, it tries to render it's content in the next place possible without interfering with the floated divs content.

Since you declared fixed width and height, there is no place for the third div to display it's content without "colliding" with the floated divs. Thats why the inner `span`-Element gets pushed below the floated divs, where the next free space for this element would be.

I hope this explained the mechanics a bit. Try to experiment with the height and width. (Commenting them out), to see the differences.

Comment: Christoph has it right. Here's a sample of the original markup and styles for people to experiment: http://jsfiddle.net/qeYPj/ . Note that if you comment out the 3rd, you see the problems the OP mentioned. This is largely a function of there being a *height* set on the divs. Delete the height line in the CSS and you get the containers not overlapping; however, the span still gets pushed down to beneath the rightmost floated div. Add the height back but also add "overflow: hidden" to see how it's the *content* that's affecting the perceived behaviour of the float. ;-)

Comment: I don't get it. There is enough room for the third span's content to be put to the right of the floated elements; why would it still be pushed down? I mean, there's no `clear` anywhere. And it's not like the third div gets pushed down.

Comment: @MrLister perhaps this fiddle makes it clearer for you: http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/Y4tTQ/1/ Floating is a difficult css-thing, it takes some time to get through it, just play with the fiddle and ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can see _that it happens_, but I don't know _why_ it happens! With the window being wide enough why doesn't this behave like a "normal" float?

Comment: Well, try [this link](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) and see if it helps you understand css-floats.

Comment: @Christoph I know about floats. But the differences between when it works as I expect, and when it works as I don't expect, are too subtle. You know what, I'll start a new question. I want to get this solved.

Comment: @MrLister I don't mean to be rude, but when a float behaves, like you didn't expect, then you still don't know exactly how floats work. It's not about knowing "about" floats, but about knowing how they work and why they behave like they do. Thats why I posted the link for you.

Comment: I just discovered what I did wrong. I tried to reset the third div's width by using `#w3-d {width:auto;}` and that didn't work, of course. Found out just in time too; I nearly started a new question. Silly me.

Comment: @MrLister so did you manage to solve your issues? (Btw. you should start accepting answers on your questions. [Why? Click here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))

Comment: @Christoph Sorry, but 17% of my questions turned out to be unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the example again, on my computer the `3` does stay inside the `#wd-3` div when I float it.

Or, if you  want the `#wd-3` div to remain constrainer to the parent block element, use `overflow:hidden` on the `#wd-c` div.